# How can I output JSON data to an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

I have some data which is being filtered in the code below. The filter works well. I've added an 'onclick' function to a button in my HTML and my data shows on screen no problem, but what I would like is when I click the button, It shows a table with the filtered data in it, and a way to exit the table, either by a box closing or click the button again and it disappears. I don't mind which.

```
function loadPRFilter(){
        var surgerySearchTerm = "pr";
        var data = jsonArray.filter(jsonObject => jsonObject.surgeryType.includes(surgerySearchTerm));
        var mainContainer = document.getElementById("pr");
                
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
          
                 div.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data[i].name + ' ' +'Score: '+ data[i].score + ' '+ 'Severity:'+' '+ data[i].severity;
                     mainContainer.appendChild(div);
                        console.log("Filtered pr");
                         console.log(data);
        }
    };
```

here is my data:

```
var jsonArray =[

    {
        "ID": 1 ,
        "name": "sub conjunctival haemorrhage",
        "score" : 1,
        "surgeryType": ["scleral buckle"] ,
        "severity" : "mild"

    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "name": "dry eye",
        "score": 5,
        "surgeryType":[ "pr" ],
        "severity" : "moderate"
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "name": "ha's",
        "score": 5,
        "surgeryType":["general", "scleral buckle", "ppv", "pr"],
        "severity" : "moderate"

    }
```

Comment: I would not indent my code like that: it is going to confuse other readers of your code, and eventually yourself. Can you edit?

Comment: Also: you speak of a button, but provide no HTML. Please turn your code into a runnable snippet, so we can see it in action (use toolbar button).